" NO SE ACCEDE A "MODULO". La importación "modulo" no se ha podido resolver desde el origen
soy nuevo en esto de la programación, así que disculpen si no me se explicar bien.
El problema es que al instalar una biblioteca externa (En este caso "sen2trash") y querer importarla a mi archivo, aparece el mensaje emergente "La importación "send2trash" no se ha podido resolver desde el origen" y ya he intentado actualizar tanto pip como python, pero nada me ha funcionado.

Probé instalar e importar el módulo en una venv (Python 3.12) y lo hizo sin problemas. Intenta instalar el módulo desde la terminal del sistema, no desde vscode o pylance. Estan en inglés, pero mira esta pregunta y esta otra.

Muchas gracias!!!
